# Comparing TextFields with a file confusion

Tags: java, user-interface

I am making a exchange app but I'm growing frustrated and having trouble with a few steps. I know what I need to do, but in order to get there I am lost, if that makes sense. I just need help with steps to take to get to my result, no direct code. The direction says "From the text file provided [currency.txt] search for the three letter currency code of the countries typed in the textFields [CurrencyTo and CurrencyFrom]. For example, if CurrencyFrom is “United States”, your code should find the currency code ‘USD’ from the currency.txt file."

I know I need to **(1) compare the country in the textbox with the country from the inputFile
and (2) if the same, then get the country code and save it in a variable.**
Any advice or breakdown on the steps I need to take is all i'm looking for. Please no direct code! Thank You

```
 class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {                 
            if(event.getSource()==calculateButton){
            String from = currencyFrom.getText();
            String to = currencyTo.getText();
            try{
            String line = "";
            File inputFile = new File("currency.txt");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
            try{
            while(in.hasNextLine()){
            line = in.nextLine();
            String[] lineContent = line.split("\t");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineContent));
            System.out.println(lineContent[0] + lineContent[1]);
            //compare the country in the textbox with the country from the inputFile
            //if they are the same, then get the country code and save it in a variable

            }
            }  
            finally{ in.close();
            }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            displayLabel.setText("File not found");}

            //go to the website and get exchagne rate and do the calculation
            String line = "";
            String address = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=" + from + to + "=X";
            try{
            URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
            try{
            while (in.hasNextLine()){
            line = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] data = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
            System.out.println(data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]);
            //display calculation
            displayLabel.setText("");
            //display last update
            updateLabel.setText("Last Updated: " + data[2] + data[3]);
            }
            }
            finally{ in.close();
            }
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException exception){
            displayLabel.setText("Website not found!");} 
            catch (IOException ex) {}

            if(event.getSource()==clearButton){
                currencyTo.setText("");
                currencyFrom.setText("");
                amount.setText("100");
                displayLabel.setText("");
                updateLabel.setText("");
            }
        }
    }  
}
        //add listener to the buttons
        ActionListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        clearButton.addActionListener(listener);
        calculateButton.addActionListener(listener);

}
}
```

Comment: Don't use empty `catch` blocks, at the very least, use `ex.printStackTrace()` so you know when and why something goes wrong

Comment: Break your problem down into individual steps.  Figure out how to make each step work in isolation, maybe using a fixed query, bring each solution together to generate an over all solution